# Set DNS to 'Obtain automatically' programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, networking, dns

Using C# on .NET, how do I set the DNS servers to 'Obtain automatically'? I can set the IP addresses to desired values like this.

```
ManagementClass mClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
ManagementObjectCollection mObjCol = mClass.GetInstances();
foreach (ManagementObject mObj in mObjCol)
{
  if ((bool)mObj["IPEnabled"])
  {
     ManagementBaseObject mboDNS = mObj.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");
     if (mboDNS != null)
     {
        //Assume X.X.X.X and X.X.X.X are the IPs.
        string[] sIPs = { "X.X.X.X", "X.X.X.X" };
        mboDNS["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = sIPs;
        mObj.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", mboDNS, null);
     }
  }
}
```

I've tried setting both IPs to null, like `sIps = { null, null };`, but that ends up not changing the settings at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting DNSServerSearchOrder to null instead of using an array of null strings.

```
ManagementClass mClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
ManagementObjectCollection mObjCol = mClass.GetInstances();
foreach (ManagementObject mObj in mObjCol)
{
  if ((bool)mObj["IPEnabled"])
  {
     ManagementBaseObject mboDNS = mObj.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");
     if (mboDNS != null)
     {
        mboDNS["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = null;
        mObj.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", mboDNS, null);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: How did I not think of that?! Thank you!

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to see wood for all those trees. Happens to me all the time. :)

Comment: Note: Setting requires running the code with either Admin privileges or by user with WMI write access.